# Applying Show and hide on dynamic XML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Here is the scenario

User select some options and send a search query.

In reply of that search request a XML is returned.

Then that XML is shown on page. This is [sample results](http://travelden.com/filter/post_flight.php?key=59cd1d9e50edb242e868a02150c6346f&search=Search) which we receive in query. This thing is applied and working in website.

Further I have to do is apply `See More` or `Show/ Hide` type thing on the results. like there are 3 **Lufthansa** results on top. Thing I want to do is that only 1 will be shown and other 2 can be hide in `href` or some `button`.

But I did not found any  `XML` and `javascript` working example. As I said before my XML is result of search query so it is dynamic `xml`. Can any one tell me how to do this thing. some tutorial or technology/language that can deal with some problem. Any help will be appreciated.